# Markov chain: join states in Transition Matrix

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

I need to merge two states in the Transition Matrix:

For example: I have the matrix below

```
      A       B       C      D      E      F 
  A  0.5     0.4      0      0      0.1    0

  B  0.5     0.1      0.2    0.1    0.1    0

  C  0       0.1      0.9    0      0      0

  D  0       0        0      0.7    0.3    0

  E  0       0.2      0      0.7    0      0.1

  F  0       0        0      0.5    0      0.5
```

And I want to join the states D and E:

```
          A      B        C    (D+E)    F 
      A  0.5     0.4      0      ?      0

      B  0.5     0.1      0.2    ?      0

      C  0       0.1      0.9    ?      0

   D+E   ?       ?        ?      ?      ?

      F  0       0        0      ?      0.5
```

What are the formulas to obtain the row and column (D+E)?

Using the constraint: "the sum over column must be equal to 1" is simple to calculate the elements:

(A,(D+E))=0.2

(B,(D+E))=0.2

(C,(D+E))=0.1

(F,(D+E))=0.5

How can I calculate the elements of row ((D+E),i)?

Comment: The main feature to mention here is that, since the path B-(DE)-F has probability zero and the path B-(DE)-(DE)-F has positive probability, the "joined" process is not a Markov chain.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/243182/hobbes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question can not be answered in general, i.e. there are no "formulas" to compute it. The reason being is that 
\begin{align*}
A(D+E,i) 
& = P(i | D \cup E ) \\ 
& = \frac{P(i | D) P(D) + P(i | E) P(E)}{P(D)+P(E)}\\
& = \frac{P(D)}{P(D)+P(E)} A(D,i) + \frac{P(E)}{P(D)+P(E)} A(E,i)
\end{align*}
and the right hand side depends essentially on $P(D)$ and $P(E).$

For your example, the question can be answered easily, e.g. using Markov chain graphs, but this is rather a "homework" level.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumpability